# Removing the file paths in the autotitle key labels in gnuplot, leaving just the filename

Tags: plot, formatting, key, gnuplot, filenames

I'm using a for loop in gnuplot to plot multiple files, according to the output of a search command. The plot command puts the whole filename in the key, including the full path. I would like to put only the filename, removing the path of directories. Is that possible?

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist

set terminal pdfcairo enhanced size 10in,7in

wmax_List = "`echo $(ls E0025/4D/Re2000/NS.dat.*[02468]000)`"

plot for [i in wmax_List] i using 1:2 with points title i
```

In this case, all the files are in the same folder. The `title i` option puts makes that **"E0025/4D/Re2000/"** appears in every line of the plot key. I could put the plotting script in that folder, but there are thousands of data files there (I'm actually plotting one every 1000), so I prefer to execute the script in its current position.

So, my question is, is there any way to remove the full path from the key? I tried using `find` instead of `ls` to generate the list of strings with just the filenames, but I don't know how to put the full path + the string in the plot command.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have different possibilities:

```
dirname = 'E0025/4D/Re2000/'
wmax_List = system('ls '.dirname.'NS.dat.*[02468]000')
ind = strlen(dirname)+1

plot for [i in wmax_List] i using 1:2 with points title i[ind:*]
```

or

```
plot for [i in wmax_List] i using 1:2 with points title system('basename '.i)
```